# Typo3 9.5.3 Site Management not working out of the box

Tags: typo3, slug, typo3-9.x

A new install of typo3 9.5.3 doesn't seem to work with Site Management

Steps to reproduce:

Server is running Centos 7 with Apache and PHP installed.
Typo3 install doesn't complain about anything during installation
Install and Enable BootStrap-Package 10.0.5 Extension
Install and Enable The Official Introduction Pages 4.0.1 Extension

Go to Sites Management --> Sites

Create a config file for the Congratulations Site with an entry point of http://testsite/

Go to url http://testsite/ set in Site Management, Homepage Shows OK

Clicking on any Menu Links results in 404 from apache

e.g

Clicking on Features

```
Not Found
The requested URL /features was not found on this server.
```

AllowOveride in turned on in my apache config and mod_rewrite is enabled.

I'm thinking this is something to do with .htaccess. Does the Site Management section write to the .htaccess, so apache knows where the content is served from?

Current htaccess is here https://pastebin.com/q29s92rV

Answer (score 0):

Site configuration doesn't write to the .htaccess.

Does it work without site configuration?

Every time I tried to install the introduction_package (4.0.1) on TYPO3 9.5.x with bootstrap_package (10.0.5), the installation did not finish properly (without an error message). May be, same problem for your installation too?